# UIProgressView not update status

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading

I have small problem with my new application. On the beginning I thought that this is only problem with threads but right now I feel that I must rewrite half of code to repair it. Before that maybe you will help me :)

Right now I am writing app which will download things from the server. We have two objects: `MainViewController` where is `UI` and `DataManager` where I am working on files. On the beginning I am checking changes on the server in `DataManager`:

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:[[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:dataURL] queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
            if (error) {
                //Data was not downloaded
            } else {
                //Downloading data base
                [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{

                    if (dataFileExists) { //compare and save downloaded data base: localDataArray i downloadedDataArray

                        if ([localDataArray isEqual:DownloadedDataArray]) {
                            [self.delegate dataWasLoaded];
                        }
                    } else {

                        [self synchronizeAllTheFiles]; //Data base sync

                        [self.delegate dataWasLoaded];
                    }

                }];
            }
        }];
```

Next when I know that there are differences on the server I synchronize all the data. There are two delegate methods: `beginUploadDataBaseWithNumberOfObjectsToDownload` and `fileWasDownloaded`.

First check how many files are to download.

Second add +1 to downloaded file. Delegate of this methods is in `MainViewController`.

```
- (void)synchronizeAllTheFiles {
    NSMutableArray *arrayWithLinksToDownload = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];                               //Table of links

    [self.delegate beginUploadDataBaseWithNumberOfObjectsToDownload:[arrayWithLinksToDownload count]]; //How many things are to download

    for (int d = 0; d < [arrayWithLinksToDownload count]; d++) { //Runloop to download links
                                          //Downloading Data

        if (urlData) {                                                                                      //If data was downloaded

            [urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];                                                  //Save on device

            [self.delegate fileWasDownloaded]; //MainViewController Add next downloaded file
        }
    }
}
```

There are delegate methods in `MainViewController`:

```
- (void)beginUploadDataBaseWithNumberOfObjectsToDownload:(int)numberToDownload {
    IfDownloadingData = YES;
    ItemsToDownloadCount = numberToDownload;
    ItemsDownloadedCount = 0;
}

- (void)fileWasDownloaded {
    ItemsDownloadedCount++;
    float progress = (float)ItemsDownloadedCount/(float)ItemsToDownloadCount;
    NSLog(@"%ld/%li - %f", (long)ItemsDownloadedCount, (long)ItemsToDownloadCount, progress);
    [self.LoadingProgressView setProgress:progress animated:YES];
}
```

The problem is that *ProgressView* do not want to update their state. At all I am trying to add dispatch block but at all if ProgressView is in main thread is not change on the screen. I am trying to manage that by `NSTimer` and dispatch books but unfortunately the problem exist.

I will be glad for any help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to put the update GUI code in main thread, not anything else.

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
     [self.LoadingProgressView setProgress:progress animated:YES];
 });
```

And then get ride of the `addOperationWithBlock` line:

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:[[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:dataURL] queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            //Data was not downloaded
        } else {
            // **Remove this line**
            // [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{

                if (dataFileExists) { //compare and save downloaded data base: localDataArray i downloadedDataArray

                    if ([localDataArray isEqual:DownloadedDataArray]) {
                        [self.delegate dataWasLoaded];
                    }
                } else {

                    [self synchronizeAllTheFiles]; //Data base sync

                    [self.delegate dataWasLoaded];
                }
            // **Remove this line**
            // }];
        }
    }];
```

And also, I don't see where you get the `urlData`. But no matter what, this loop should not be in the main thread as it will keep the main thread busy and therefore could not update your GUI.

```
for (int d = 0; d < [arrayWithLinksToDownload count]; d++) { //Runloop to download links

        //Downloading Data

        if (urlData) {                                                                                     
            //If data was downloaded
            [urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];                                                 
            //Save on device
            [self.delegate fileWasDownloaded]; //MainViewController Add next downloaded file
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for help! Everything is working right now :D